# Does this "are" imply "can"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But whether that gift be present in greater or in lesser degree, the
>   character and ideas of a statesman **are** best studied through his
>   own words.

So what's the meaning of this "are?"
Does this imply "can"?

It can be studied very well through his words?

Comment: *are ... studied* is merely the passive. The further meaning is supplied by the adverb *best*. "The best way to study a statesman's character and ideas is through his own words".

Comment: When two or more qualities of a person are described, then the plural of the verb is used. So, here "are" is used..

Comment: I agree with @StoneyB, it is not talking of can. It is stating the best way to study a statesman's character.

Comment: @StoneyB, You should add an answer.Your interpretation is exact.

Comment: @Sweet72: You'd have to get up *very* early in the morning to catch StoneyB out in a basic error such as you suspect! The singular form of the verb is used because there's only *one* "best way". Grammatically, that's still the case if we're talking about doing multiple activities (the best way to *discover and understand*), and/or multiple people under study (the best way to study *world leaders*), and/or multiple aspects of the individual(s) under study *(character and ideas)*.

Answer (score 2):

> It can be studied very well through his words?

No. *Are* is never *can* in English. The author is saying, “It is best studied through his words.”

> the character and ideas of a statesman are best studied through his own words.

Another way of saying this is:

*If you want to understand the character and ideas of a statesman, it is best to examine what they themselves have to say.*

Or in more simple English:

*To understand a politician’s beliefs, you should listen to what the politician says about these beliefs (instead of what others have to say about them).*